# symbols in a function to "take on" the values of controls with the same names in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, symbols

(** I want the symbols a1... in f1... to "take on" the values of the controls with the same names in Manipulate[Plot[f1[3,"a"],{x,1,3}],{a1,0,1},{a2,0,1},{a3,0,1}]. Here's what I've tried-  **)

```
f1[n_, c_String] := Table[Symbol[c <> ToString[i]] x^i, {i, n}]

f1[3, "a"]
```

(** Out[202]={a1 x, a2 x^2, a3 x^3} **)

(** Works: cut & paste the Out[202] string {a1 x,a2 x^2,a3 x^3} into Plot[...] **)

```
Manipulate[Plot[{a1 x, a2 x^2, a3 x^3}, {x, 1, 3}], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, {a3,0, 1}]
```

(** Works: put Out[202] string %202 into Plot[...] **)

```
Manipulate[Plot[%202, a3 x^3}, {x, 1, 3}], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, {a3,0, 1}]
```

(** Blank plot: put the function f1[3,"a"] into Plot[...] **)

```
Manipulate[Plot[f1[3, "a"], {x, 1, 3}], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, {a3, 0, 1}]
```

(** Blank plot: variations on put the function f1[3,"a"] into
Plot[...] **)

```
Manipulate[Plot[{f1[3, "a"]}, {x, 1, 3}], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, {a3, 0, 1}]

Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[f1[3, "a"]], {x, 1, 3}], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, {a3,0, 1}]

Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{f1[3, "a"]}], {x, 1, 3}], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, {a3,0, 1}]
```

Thanks

Comment: `Manipulate[Plot[%202, a3 x^3}, {x, 1, 3}], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, {a3,0, 1}]` contains a syntax error.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
f[n_, c_]:=With[
  {
    expr = Table[Symbol[c<>ToString[i]] x^i,{i,n}],
    controls = Sequence@@Table[{Symbol[c<>ToString[i]], 0, 1}, {i, n}]
  },
  Manipulate[Plot[expr, {x, 1, 3}], controls]
]
```

`f[3, "a"]` will then give you a manipulate with `a1`, `a2`, `a3`.

Comment: @mk_newbie A simpler solution using the same idea is `With[{arg = f1[3, "a"]},
 Manipulate[Plot[arg, {x, 1, 3}], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, {a3, 0, 1}]]`.  The issue is described in the "Possible Issues" section of the `Manipulate` documentation, "Manipulate only "notices" explicit visible parameters:".